# How can I locate the merge module that I need for my installer?

Tags: windows, installation

I have an MSI file which I include the following merge modules modules:

```
  <Merge Id="VCRedistVC90CRT" SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
  <Merge Id="VCRedistVC100CRT" SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
  <Merge Id="VCRedistVC90MFC" SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC90_MFC_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
  <Merge Id="VCRedistVC90ATL" SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
```

Which is all well and good but its not enough for my application to run on a virgin machine.  If I install the VS2008 SP1 re-distributable exe from the Microsoft site the application launches just fine.

I have determined which folders are missing in the C:\Windows\WinSxs folder however I have no means to determine the merge module that would contain the components that I require.

Why are the merge modules in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\" not sufficient?  And where can I find the correct module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the policy merge modules.